# How to change color of string, and popup some interface status?

Tags: php, html, shell

First my english is not very good sorry! I try to make if ifOperStatus = UP the show in Green color if ifOperStatus = Down to show in RED color.
For this i will try this options:

```
if($IfOperStatus["up"] == "up")
{
    echo "up";
}
else if ($IfOperStatus["down"] == "down")
{
    echo "$down.";
}
```

for now with this script the result is like this:

```
echo '<td>Състояние: '.$IfOperStatus.'</td>';
echo '<td>Състояние: '.$IfOperStatus.'</td>';

Състояние: up(1)
Състояние: down(2)
```

If it is possible and otherwise to be done I am open to the idea. The end result is important to me.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script>
   $("td#popup").bind("click",function() {
      location = "http://www.test.url";
   });
</script>



<?php

$time1= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ip='172.10.10.1';
$ro='public';
$session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2C, $ip, $ro);
$ifDescr = $session->walk(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2", TRUE);

$ifAlias = $session->walk("IF-MIB::ifAlias", TRUE);

$ifSpeed = $session->walk(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5", TRUE);

$ifLastChange = $session->walk("IF-MIB::ifLastChange", TRUE);

$ifOperStatus = $session->walk(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8", TRUE);

$ifInErrors = $session->walk(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.14", TRUE);

$ifOutErrors = $session->walk(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.20", TRUE);

$ONUMAC = $session->walk("1.3.6.1.4.1.3320.101.10.1.1.3", TRUE);

$ONURxLevel = $session->walk("1.3.6.1.4.1.3320.101.10.5.1.5", TRUE);

$ONUTemp = $session->walk("1.3.6.1.4.1.3320.101.10.5.1.2", TRUE);

$ONUDist = $session->walk("1.3.6.1.4.1.3320.101.10.1.1.27", TRUE);

$ONUVendor = $session->walk("1.3.6.1.4.1.3320.101.10.1.1.1", TRUE);

$ONUModel = $session->walk("1.3.6.1.4.1.3320.101.10.1.1.2", TRUE);

        foreach ($ifDescr as $key => $value) {
        $iface[$key]['IfId']=$key;
        $value=explode(' ', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $value = str_replace("\"", "", $value);
        $iface[$key]['IfDescr']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ifAlias as $key => $value) {
        $iface[$key]['IfId']=$key;
        $value=explode(' ', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $value = str_replace("\"", "", $value);
        $iface[$key]['ifAlias']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ifSpeed as $key => $value) {
        $value=explode(':', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $iface[$key]['IfSpeed']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ifLastChange as $key => $value) {
    $iface[$key]['IfId']=$key;
//  list($not1, $not2, $num1, $theday, $time1)=explode(" ", $value);
        $value=explode('  ', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
//  $value = str_replace("\"", "", $value);
        $iface[$key]['ifLastChange']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ifOperStatus as $key => $value) {
        $value=explode(':', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $iface[$key]['IfOperStatus']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ifInErrors as $key => $value) {
        $value=explode(':', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $iface[$key]['IfInErrors']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ifOutErrors as $key => $value) {
        $value=explode(':', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $iface[$key]['IfOutErrors']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ONUMAC as $key => $value) {
        $value=explode(':', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $value = str_replace (" ", ":", $value);
        $iface[$key]['ONUMAC']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ONURxLevel as $key => $value) {
        $value=explode(':', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $iface[$key]['ONURxLevel']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ONUTemp as $key => $value) {
        $value=explode(':', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $value = $value/256;
        $value = round($value, 2);
        $iface[$key]['ONUTemp']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ONUDist as $key => $value) {
        $value=explode(':', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $iface[$key]['ONUDist']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ONUVendor as $key => $value) {
        $value=explode(':', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $value = str_replace("\"", "", $value);
        $iface[$key]['ONUVendor']=$value;
        }
        foreach ($ONUModel as $key => $value) {
        $value=explode(':', $value);
        $value=end($value);
        $value=trim($value);
        $value = str_replace("\"", "", $value);
        $iface[$key]['ONUModel']=$value;
        }




    echo "$time1.<h2></h2>";
    echo '<table>';
    foreach ($iface as $key){
    $date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
//        $IfId=$equipment_id.'_'.$key['IfId'];
        $IfDescr=$key['IfDescr'];
        $ifAlias=$key['ifAlias'];
        $IfSpeed=$key['IfSpeed'];
        $ifLastChange=$key['ifLastChange'];
        $IfOperStatus=$key['IfOperStatus'];
        $IfInErrors=$key['IfInErrors'];
        $IfOutErrors=$key['IfOutErrors'];
        if(isset( $key['ONUMAC'])){
        $ONUMAC=$key['ONUMAC'];}else{$ONUMAC=NULL;}
        if(isset( $key['ONURxLevel'])){
        $ONURxLevel=$key['ONURxLevel']/10;}else{$ONURxLevel=NULL;}
        if(isset( $key['ONUTemp'])){
        $ONUTemp=$key['ONUTemp'];}else{$ONUTemp=NULL;}
        if(isset( $key['ONUDist'])){
        $ONUDist=$key['ONUDist'];}else{$ONUDist=NULL;}
//      if(isset( $key['ONUVendor'])){
//      $ONUVendor=$key['ONUVendor'];}else{$ONUVendor=NULL;}
//      if(isset( $key['ONUModel'])){
//      $ONUModel=$key['ONUModel'];}else{$ONUModel=NULL;}
//      $ONUVendorModel=$ONUVendor.'/'.$ONUModel;
//  echo '<td>IfId: '.$IfId.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$IfDescr.'</td>';
        echo '<td>Адрес: '.$ifAlias.'</td>';
//        echo '<td>IfSpeed: '.$IfSpeed.'</td>';
//  echo '<td>ifLastChange: '.$num1.$theday.$time1.'</td>';
        echo '<td>Uptime: '.$ifLastChange.'</td>';

    if($IfOperStatus["up"] == "up")
    {
        echo "up";
    }
    else if ($IfOperStatus["down"] == "down")
    {
        echo "$down.";
    }

        echo '<td>Състояние: '.$IfOperStatus.'</td>';
//        echo '<td>IfInErrors: '.$IfInErrors.'</td>';
//        echo '<td>IfOutErrors: '.$IfOutErrors.'</td>';
//  echo '</br>';
        $epon=stripos($IfDescr, 'pon');
        $eponslash=stripos($IfDescr, '/');
        $eponcolon=stripos($IfDescr, ':');
        if($epon !== false and $eponslash!== false and $eponcolon !== false){
        echo '<td>MAC: '.$ONUMAC.'</td>';
        echo '<td>Сигнал: '.$ONURxLevel.'</td>';
        echo '<td>Температура: '.$ONUTemp.'</td>';
        echo '<td>Растояние: '.$ONUDist.'</td>';}
//        echo '<td>ONUVendor: '.$ONUVendor.'</td>';
//        echo '<td>ONUModel: '.$ONUModel.'</td>'; }
//  echo '</br>';

    echo '</tr>';

}

    echo '</table>';


?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the element you want to change color?

Comment: "$ifOperStatus"

Comment: this is my php html output in browser

`EPON0/1 Адрес:  Uptime: Timeticks: (319870324) 37 days, 0:31:43.24 Състояние: up(1)
EPON0/2 Адрес:  Uptime: Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00 Състояние: down(2)
EPON0/3 Адрес:  Uptime: Timeticks: (319870323) 37 days, 0:31:43.23 Състояние: up(1)
EPON0/4 Адрес:  Uptime: Timeticks: (319870320) 37 days, 0:31:43.20 Състояние: up(1)`

i wanna maka Състояние: "up(1)" to make to be a green color
and "Състояние: down(2)" to make to be a red color

Comment: I think I understand? You want to change the text color depending on the value of column or roll? If so you can check the value of the column in php and add a style or css class of the color you want to it before displaying it OR you can use javascript to grab the elements check their value and apply a css class or style of the appropriate color

Comment: i don`t know how to make this